# ESD protection of an input button

Tags: emc, input, tvs

I was asked to design a EMI-protected button. A schematic below.

[image]

Let me explain all that stuff

- a C39 capacitor suppresses high voltages
- an R44 resistor limits the current coming from an ESD discharge
- a D29 diode is a TVS diode

Did I place the TVS diode correctly? I placed it behind the resistor so that the current that has lower value and then the TVS diode would deal with lower energy.

What do you think?

Comment: Where is the EMI threat occurring in your circuit? What are you trying to protect? What level of EMI is it? Do you actually mean ESD?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka. I got ESD on mind. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

C39 is a bad idea - the poor switch won’t like discharging it. In most cases, C29 would be adequate on its own. Depends on pcb layout and what standard you need to comply with.

The circuit you’ve shown would be more suited to a signal from the outside world that has some length.

Answer (score 0):

> a C39 capacitor suppresses high voltages

Capacitors don't do that. If they generally did, there'd be no market for TVS diodes.

That capacitor should go.

I'm not sure to what extent C29 would make a difference, but it probably doesn't hurt.

> I placed it behind the resistor so that the current that has lower value and then the TVS diode would deal with lower energy.

If R44 is not rated for several-kV-level pulses, you should assume it's a short, unless you take time to characterize it with an ESD gun and get reproducible results that indicate that it's not a short.

I'm 99% sure that unless R44 is a physically large, high-voltage-rated part, it will simply break down, since it will see the full ESD voltage across it, as the other end is shorted to 0V via the TVS diode.

If the series resistor were to be placed *after* the TVS diode, it'd have a much better chance at not breaking down, and at limiting the current into the MCU pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE8kNK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'd do as above, and leave the place in the layout for D2. You can remove it if the ESD tests are satisfactory without it.

As with all switch outputs, the MCU should perform debouncing in software.

Comment: ">a C39 capacitor suppresses high voltages

Capacitors don't do that. If they generally did, there'd be no market for TVS diodes."

This is not entirely true. Based on the principle of conservation of charge, the final ESD voltage produced by its capacitance is the ESD charge divided by the ESD model capacitance (usually human body model) and the pin capacitance. This still may result in a surge voltage greater than that acceptable at the pin, but typically there are clamping diodes at the pins plus any series resistance to limit the current across them.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently making my first steps in EMC design.

That being said, yesterday I was at a testing facility the first time to test my product. There were no major problems, but when the ESD probe got near a certain area of my casing, the system would act as if the button was pressed.

On closer inspection, I noticed, that in this area are the wires that lead to the button (inside the casing). The button is made of plastic (non conductive material), so there is no risk of a surge connecting directly to a metallic part of the circuit.

[image]

However, it seems that the electrical field of the probe has induced a voltage spike in the wires that lead to the pushbutton. How high the induced voltage is, I cannot say. Currently, the input wire, that leads to the uC, is only "protected" by 490 pF (the value is probably a bit low, 100 nF seem more suited) leading to ground. The uC has an internal pull-up on this line. When the button is pressed, it is connected to ground.

So in your case: Is your button made of a conductive material? I don´t see why you would need a TVS diode, if your button is non conductive. I would just assume, that the induced voltage from the probe is not higher than the max. tolerated voltage of the uC, but I cannot say for sure. A resistor and a capacitor would seem to be adequate elements to filter the input signal and make it a low pass. However, this is just my first impression and I will have to do further testing in this regard.

Comment: Assuming a tactile switch or similar, ESD from a finger may as well transfer to the component legs of the switch - so it isn't very relevant if the switch body is conductive or not. During ESD testing there will always be air discharges. Now, most modern IC have protection diodes on the input pins to counter ESD. However they may not be enough for some scenarios, you'll have to check how many kV they are specified to handle. A pull-up is pretty useless to counter ESD, you need a series resistor and/or TVS.

Comment: As for why your MCU (?) would interpret a spike as a key press, that sounds like a software bug, such as not even implementing basic de-bouncing. Since de-bouncing also acts as a software filter against spikes.

Comment: Most likely, partial discharge (sparks tracking along the surface of the insulator) generated enough impulse to charge C38 beyond a logic level.  Such a short "press" should've been ignored by the digital debounce filter (you do debounce, right?).

Comment: Also along @Lundin 's lines, note that ESD diodes are there to protect the device from catastrophic failure, not to maintain operation; activation while powered may result in CMOS latchup, requiring a power cycle to clear (or maybe the device overheats and fails anyway). A TVS or clamp diodes, or much larger capacitor (assuming the debounce/filter time constant is acceptable), will be desirable for this reason.

Comment: @TimWilliams Actually latch-up might very well be what happened here. And indeed the internal diodes shouldn't be relied upon in scenarios where ESD is expected. And in case of a switch, ESD is always expected, so...

Comment: @Lundin yes, of course, it depends on the type of switch. This switch is mounted in a hole in the casing and has a huge polymer trigger, that is not conductive. ESD testing showed, that it is uncritical, so I don´t use a TVS diode or something on that line.

I am using the STM32WB55RGXX, if anyone is interested. The pins of all ICs I am using on that pcb are ESD protected. Still, for the connectors, that actually go outside of the casing, I am using TVS diodes for additional protection.

Comment: Oh no, I am not debouncing in the code. That IS actually a very good idea. You see, the code that is triggered by the button, lasts ~0,5 seconds, so I did not see the need to debounce, as this delay "debounces" the switch in a way. But it seems very reasonable to add an additional debounce filter (in software) to counter the effects of ESD. I like the concept, that hardware protects the device from critical damage and the software deals with the signal issues...

Comment: So I assume, that the ESD discharge (in the air) induces a voltage in the lines of the button inside the casing. Does anybody know how high these voltages can be over a short distance? There is NO spark and no direct contact. Anyway, the uC is protected per its design. I am just thinking how you would debounce this issue in hardware. Wouldn´t a low pass filter (with a series resistor and a capacitor to ground) filter short ESD spikes, if the voltage is not too high?

Comment: The comment field on this site isn't the place to teach you all these things, but let me just say that in case of ESD the concern is always non-conductive materials such as plastic which may build up charge, as well as metal areas that are exposed but not grounded. The voltage levels (contact and air) for various classes are specified in the ESD standard IEC 61000-4-2, the toughest being 8kV contact 15kV air for high integrity systems. Automotive/aerospace/military have even higher requirements.